# Laravel login form, how to show what user inputed which data?

Tags: php, laravel

I created auth login form,
created input forms to different tables with foreign keys to users.
Problem is i have 10 users each has their id like autoinc id.
though when i log in and  submit inputted data with user who got id 4, and user who got id 7, and in database it shows that all inputed data was created by user whom id is 1...
So how to make that that when user with id 4 inputs data it would show as 4 user_id in foreign key.

Comment: Please provide the code that is saving this data. We cannot help you without you showing us how you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the Laravel tutorial for authentication before trying anything new with it.

We can't answer a question without knowing what is exactly the problem you are facing, and that's even harder without any code.

Laravel has one of the best documentations I've seen, so I really enforce using their documentation before anything else.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auth

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 $user = Auth::user();
 $user->id;
```